# Pysolr filter search

Tags: solr, pysolr

I am using pysolr-2.0.15 api for Solr searching

```
mysite:8983/solr/select/?q=disease&fq=url:"pediatric"&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

This Solr query gives me successful result

I want to implement this using pysolr search function

I am trying this one:

```
results = conn.search('disease "url:Pediatric"')
```

But results are not correct.

Another problem is that the search method returns only 10 records; how can I get all search results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should pass the `fq` and `rows` as arguments:

```
results = conn.search('disease', fq='url:Pediatric', rows=100)
```

Note that you can pass multiple fq parameters:

```
filter_queries = ['url:Pediatric', 'otherparam:othervalue']
results = conn.search('disease', fq=filter_queries, rows=100)
```

Comment: How to make AND condition while passing multiple fq parameters?